# Google Search is displaying empty pages but those pages are non-existent

Tags: seo, wordpress, https

My WordPress site in Google Search is showing non-existent navigation pages, like 10 of 730 when I search `site:example.com`. However I only have 3670 posts.

When I click on the pages it leads to empty page, which is affecting my website traffic. I installed SSL and configured it using an SSL plugin, but the search results are still showing mixed content of other website. Please check attached screenshot:

[image: google search results]

Comment: Look's like you've changed your site theme recently, because right now your homepage does not show navigation pages which is index earlier by Google when you're using old theme with page navigation.

Comment: Your visitors don't use `site:` command therefore those pages are unlikely to be found since no visitor is going to type `newkannada Page 337 songs `. Add `disallow: /page/` to robots.txt and problem is sorted. Also... if you don't own the rights to share those media files your site will in time receive a DCMA complaint and then you can say good bye to your rankings overnight.